# how to append to a object with innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add information to a DOM object with .innerHTML without replacing what exists there?

For example: `document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = 'stuff';`

Would return `<div id="div">stuff</div>`

And then a similar call: `document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = ' and things';`

Would set the div to `<div id="div">stuff and things</div>`

Comment: Answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387433/fastest-way-to-append-html-content-to-a-div-using-javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = 'stuff'
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += 'and things'
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += 'and even more'
```

Comment: this gives me an `ERROR TypeError: "document.getElementById(...)` is null" when used in typescript

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

> insertAdjacentHTML() parses the specified text as HTML or XML and **inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position**. It does not reparse the element it is being used on and thus it does not corrupt the existing elements inside the element. This, and avoiding the extra step of serialization make it much faster than direct innerHTML manipulation.

If you want to append your `stuff` at the end of this `Element`, you would do

```
const div = document.getElementById("div");
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'stuff');;
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

The [+= operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

Answer (score 3):

why not try

```
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += ' and things';
```

note the "+"

Comment: This will remove all events attached to existen elements inside of the div

Answer (score 1):

There are mistakes in your examples. But you could just do this:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('div');

myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML + ' and things';
```

Comment: +1 for identifying that there were mistakes in the OP source.

Answer (score 0):

change it to this:

```
document.getElementById.innerHTML('div') = 
    document.getElementById.innerHTML('div') + ' and things';
```

the ol' x = x+1 style of concatenation.

though I don't think "document.getElementById.innerHTML('div')" is even proper syntax? Don't you mean "document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML"?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe:

```
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('div').innerHTML + ' and things'
```